# Story about a girl who predicts a weapons satellite will malfunction and destroy the planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm asking this question on behalf of a friend, who posted about this story on Facebook a few months ago. This is my recollection of their recollection, but luckily my long-term memory is pretty good.

The United States elect a populist demagogue as their President, and among other things, he changes the American flag to a new gold-coloured design. He also announces the construction of some kind of futuristic weapons satellite, which he intends to launch into Earth's orbit.

The story's protagonist, a young girl, then has an apparently prophetic dream: during the satellite's launch, some kind of mishap will occur that causes the satellite to malfunction and ignite the Earth's atmosphere, killing all life on the planet. She leads a group of protesters to the White House, and after talking with her and learning of her prophetic dream, the President agrees to cancel the satellite's launch.

I believe my friend read this 10-15 years ago, that it was in English, and that it *may* have been a short story (I'm afraid I don't quite remember that detail).

Comment: Daft question but do you not know where the Facebook post is anymore?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm afraid not. I could try and track it down, but like I said, it was several months ago now.